# looking for an appropriate idiom

Tags: idiom-requests

I'm looking for an idiom which describes a situation when someone is not able to focus on his work.
I want to use in this line:
TV, laptop etc came to my life. The consequence was that I could not keep myself engrossed in the book

Answer (score 3):

[drive you to distraction](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/distraction)

Mine:"Today's modern gadgetry drives people to distraction"

Consequently you could adapt this to your situation,

> Since laptops, smart phones, iPads etc. have come into my life I've been
>   driven to distraction and unable to concentrate on my reading.

or

> Laptops, smart phones, iPads etc. drive **me** to distraction, consequently
>   I'm unable to do any serious reading.